# How can I read my objects in XCode lldb as first state JSON in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have some objects which have Codable protocol so they coming from service API and turn into dictionaries. There are lots of Service function in the project so I can not fetch the the point where they turn into JSON or dictionary and I can not the see first state of these objects.

So is there any way so that i can see that dictionary values in console or somewhere else even if they had already become JSON ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension to convert it from dictionary to JSON and by using it you can print it in the console.

```
extension Dictionary {
    var json: String {
        let invalidJson = "Not a valid JSON"
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            return String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? invalidJson
        } catch {
            return invalidJson
        }
    }

    func printJson() {
        print(json)
    }
}
```

suppose you have `yourDicObj` decoded from JSON and you want to see it as JSON before decoded on the console

**usage** in console :

```
lldb po yourDicObj.printJson
```

---

it will print as JSON